# geometric Significance of flat maps.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is the geometric significance of flat maps of modules? 
Would appreciate an answer which would avoid knowledge of schemes.

Comment: What is a flat map of modules ?

Comment: Maybe you mean a flat ring map?

Comment: Perhaps this mathoverflow answer could be interesting: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6789/why-are-flat-morphisms-flat